# How to transform a loss function into a score function?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

Loss_Function/Maximize_Function/Score_Function, CustomLoss, pytorch.
Using Custom Loss for Maximizing Score in PyTorch

I'm using a PyTorch model with an LSTM input layer, a linear hidden layer, and 3 neurons in the output layer with a softmax activation function.

Instead of using a loss function (such as nn.MSELoss()) and passing the model's prediction and its target (loss = criterion(predictions, target)), I would like to use a custom scoring function that I've created. This scoring function is represented as score = get_score(predictions), which implies a concept similar to maximizing (predictions, score).

However, since I don't possess a target for each input value of the model, the model would be evaluated based on its score (which is a single number). It appears that considering a single value as a basis for assessing a set of predictions across the entire dataset might not be valid.

Is something like this possible? The times I've attempted it, I often encounter an error during the 'loss'.backward() phase, as it fails to trace the necessary gradients for backpropagation.

I didn't put the code because it's a very big code, but I'll make a simple example.

```
class Model_123(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(10, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.linear1(x)
        out = F.softmax(out, dim=1)
        return out 

dataset = torch.randn(10, 10)
model = Model_123()

custom_loss_score = CustomLoss_Score()  # This is what I want to figure out
for epoch in range(epochs):

    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    predictions = model(dataset)
    score = random.uniform(0, 100)

    # Random score just for demonstration, but it would be calculated based on the model's actions.
    # Using torch.argmax on the predictions made by the model for that input value.
    # This gives me a success rate, where correctly predicting action 0 or action 1 gets +1,
    # while action 2 means doing nothing. In a situation where the model correctly predicts only one action,
    # between actions 0 and 1, and everything else is action 2, leading to a 100% success rate.
    # This scenario is not good as there's no criteria; it just guessed one action and got 100% score.
    # It would be better if the model correctly predicted 80% of actions with a 70% operation rate,
    # which would be a better outcome. So, based on the success rate, I create another function
    # to calculate the score, a relation between the success rate and the number of operations performed.
    # This is a much larger code that I haven't included here.

    loss_score = custom_loss_score(predictions, score)  # Maximize the score
    loss_score.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

This scoring mechanism, represented as score, would ideally be maximized by adjusting the model's parameters. However, I'm unsure about how to define the CustomLoss_Score() function that would achieve this.

The score is generated based on the model's actions, and it's calculated using a relationship between the accuracy rate and the number of operations performed. The intention is to maximize this score rather than minimizing a traditional loss function.

Comment: You should not be asking vague questions like if its possible, you should include all code to reproduce the problem, as everything depends on exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Post code. But in general, you are welcome to define loss functions with no target, and these are commonly employed for data regularization, sparsity, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Added more information about my question.